# How do I fetch all methods from a given namespace?

Tags: .net, class, reflection, namespaces

I want all the Method-ClassName from namespace

like i have system.windows.Forms

wehen in visual studio we rigt system.windows.Forms. it will suggest box of all the related method,class,enum extra

i need to fetch the same ,how can i do that in C#

Answer (score 5):

For a start, there are no methods in a namespace - only types.

To get all the types from one namespace within a particular assembly, you can use (assuming .NET 3.5 for the LINQ bit) [Assembly.GetTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes.aspx):

```
var types = assembly.GetTypes().Where(type => type.Namespace == desiredNamespace);
```

Types can be spread across multiple assemblies, however.

Once you've got a type, you can use [Type.GetMethods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getmethods.aspx) to retrieve the methods available. Use appropriate BindingFlags to get static/instance, public/non-public methods etc.

If this doesn't help, please clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of functionality is called "reflection".

http://www.codersource.net/published/view/291/reflection_in.aspx for example (which I found by Googling for 'reflection' and 'C#') mentions relevent .NET API methods which you invoke from C#.